# How to package vocabulary file for Cloud ML Engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have a .txt file which contains a different label on each line. I use this file to create a label index lookup file, for example:

```
label_index = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file = 'labels.txt'
```

I am wondering how I should package the vocabulary file with my cloud ml-engine? The [packaging suggestions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer) are explicit in how to set up the .py files but I am not entirely sure where I should put relevant .txt files.  Should they just be hosted in a storage bucket (ie. gs://) that the engine has access to, or can they be packaged with the trainer somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options. I think the most straightforward is to store `labels.txt` in a GCS location.

However, if you prefer, you can also package the file up in your `setup.py`. There are multiple ways to do this, so I'll refer you to the [official setuptools documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

Let me walk through a quick example:

Create a `setup.py` in the directory below your training package (often called `trainer` in CloudML Engine's samples, so I will proceed as if you're code is structured the same as the samples, including using `trainer` as the package). The following is based on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer) you referenced with one important change, namely, the `package_data` argument instead of `include_package_data`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_model',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'trainer': ['labels.txt']},
    description='My trainer application package.'
)
```

If you run `python setup.py sdist`, you can see that `trainer/labels.txt` was copied into the tarball.

Then in your code, you can access the file like this:

```
from pkg_resources import Requirement, resource_filename
resource_filename(Requirement.parse('trainer'),'labels.txt')
```

Note that to run this code locally, you're going to have to install your package: `python setup.py install [--user]`.

And that's the primary reason I think storing the file on GCS might be easier.