# Packaging keras tokenizer/word index for use in google-cloud-ml-engine

Tags: python, keras, google-cloud-ml-engine

I've created a text classifier in Keras, and I can train the Keras model on Cloud ML just fine: the model is subsequently deployed on Cloud ML. However, when passing along text to classify, it returns the wrong classifications: I suspect strongly that it's not using the same tokenizer/word index that I have used when creating the keras classifier, and that was used to tokenise the new text.

I'm unsure how to pass along the tokeniser/word index to Cloud ML when training: there is a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641474/how-to-package-vocabulary-file-for-cloud-ml-engine), but will

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training
```

pick up a pickle or text file containing the word index mapping? And if so, how should I configure the setup.py file?

---

EDIT:

So, I'm using Keras to tokenise input text like so:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
```

If I'm just loading a Keras model locally, I save the model like so:

```
model.save('model_embeddings_20epochs_v2.h5')
```

I also save the tokenizer, so that I can use it to tokenize new data:

```
with open("../saved_models/keras_tokenizer_embeddings_002.pickle", "wb") as f:
   pickle.dump(tokenizer, f)
```

On new data, I restore the model and tokenizer.

```
model = load_model('../../saved_models/model_embeddings_20epochs_v2.h5')
with open("../../saved_models/keras_tokenizer_embeddings_002.pickle", "rb") as f:
   tokenizer = pickle.load(f)
```

I then use the tokenizer to convert text to sequences on the new data, classify etc.

The script for the Cloud ML job does not save the tokenizer - I presumed that Keras script basically used the same word index.

```
....
X_train = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in X_train]
X_test = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in X_test]

# finally, vectorize the text samples into a 2D integer tensor
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
```

.....

```
# prepare embedding matrix
num_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index))
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= MAX_NB_WORDS:
        continue
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

# load pre-trained word embeddings into an Embedding layer
# note that we set trainable = False so as to keep the embeddings fixed
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

At the moment, I'm just training it locally.

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
             --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
--module-name trainer.multiclass_glove_embeddings_v1 \
--package-path ./trainer \
-- \
--train-file ./data/corpus.pkl
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets or links to your code or otherwise provide more context into how you are using the word index mapping?

Comment: Code/context now added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/702d595822e9e5f5232b8140c6296683612c33a9/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/preprocessing/text.py#L112), it appears that even TensorFlow's Keras-compatible library is doing Tokenization *in Python*, i.e., not as part of the TensorFlow graph.

At this time, CloudML Engine only supports serving TensorFlow models where all of the logic is encoded in a TensorFlow graph. That means you'll have to do the tokenization client side and pass the results onto the server for prediction. This would involve coding the *client* to deserialize the `Tokenizer` and call `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences` for the inputs for which predictions are desired.

We recognize that this is not always ideal (a non-starter for non-Python clients and inconvenient, at least, even for Python clients) and are actively investigating solutions for allowing arbitrary Python code to be run as part of prediction.